# How to update panel from datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Commandbutton with id("myButtonId2") works fine. I mean it updates "myOutputPanel" but commandbutton which is inside datatable doesn't update outputPanel. Is there a specific update style for datatables?

```
<h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">
  <p:panel id="myPanel">
     <p:dataTable id="myDatatable">
        <p:column style="width:4%">  
          <p:commandButton id="myButtonId" update="myOutputPanel"/>
        </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
     <p:commandButton id="myButtonId2" update="myOutputPanel"/>
    </p:panel>

 <p:outputPanel id="myOutputPanel">
  //some stuff
 </p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because with `process` and `update` they work much the same way as the `f:ajax` component attributes `execute` and `render` do.  One can only reference the id of a component directly if they reside within the same `NamingContainer`.

The clientID is generated by prefixing the naming container ids seperated by `:` by default.  The `p:panel` component does not implement `NamingContainer` although `h:form` and `p:dataTable` do implement `NamingContainer`.

The clientID of `myOutputPanel` is as follows:

```
myForm:myOutputPanel
```

The second button works because it is outside of the dataTable and relative to `myOutputPanel` in the same NamingContainer which is the form.  To reference the absolute clientID in `process` or `update` one can prefix the clientID with the `:` symbol.

Try changing the `update` attribute of the first commandButton to:

```
:myForm:myOutputPanel
```

This should allow it absolutely reference its generated clientID and work.

Comment: I am getting this error. "Cannot find component with identifier ":myForm:myOutputPanel" referenced from "tabView:myDatatable:0:myButtonId"". By the way this page is inside a tab and tabview's id is "tabView".

Comment: I tried also "tabView:myOutputPanel" and ":tabView:myOutputPanel" and ":myOutputPanel". None of them worked.

Comment: @TurgutDsfadfa TabView is also a NamingContainer but it is build on a `ui:repeat` so you can't directly access an absolute clientID for this.  You would either need to update the entire TabView or you can use the `@form` reserved value to update all elements inside of `myForm`.

Comment: Try :myForm:tabView:myOutputPanel